# We wrote service descriptors for windows service in which user does not have privilege to start/stop the service but Admin can Start/Stop the service

Tags: windows, service, acl, user-permissions, taskmanager

We are trying to make a service which is entirely controlled by the admin and the user does not have access to do anything like start, stop, restart or change startup type of the service or end the service using task manager.
At this stage our SDDL looks like: D:P(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRCWD;;;SY)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRCWD;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRCWD;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)

This SDDL gives the following permissions:
NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE: Access: Allow, Permissions: This Object Only - CreateChild, Self, ListObject, ExtendedRight, GenericExecute, WriteDacl
AUTHORITY\SYSTEM: Access: Allow, Permissions: This Object Only - CreateChild, Self, ExtendedRight, GenericRead, WriteDacl
BUILTIN\Administrators: Access: Allow, Permissions: This Object Only - CreateChild, Self, ExtendedRight, GenericRead, WriteDacl

Currently no one can stop the service, but we want only the admin to have privilege to stop the service, We need help with setting up SDDL for the same!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is still relevant, but you need the ACE string "WP". This allows the relevant identity (mentioned in the SID string) to start/stop the service. So if you want to let admins the ability to stop and start, you need to use the following (the "BA" SID string stands for Built-in administrators, you can also add the SID of the administrator account):

```
D:(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRCWDWP;;;BA)
```

In context of what you wrote:

```
D:P(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRCWD;;;SY)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRCWD;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRCWDWP;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```